# Rails_admin and Active_storage

Tags: rails-admin, rails-activestorage

I am trying to upload multiple files through `Rails_Admin` with `Active_Storage`.
Here is my code :

```
  belongs_to :driver
  has_one_attached :avatar
  has_many_attached :pictures


  attr_accessor :remove_avatar
  after_save { asset.purge if remove_avatar == '1' }


  attr_accessor :remove_pictures
  after_save do
    Array(remove_pictures).each { |id| pictures.find_by_id(id).try(:purge) }
  end


  rails_admin do
    field :driver_id
    field :avatar, :active_storage
    field :pictures, :multiple_active_storage


  end
```

I get only one field for the pictures. I've tried to copy past the field several time like this

```
rails_admin do
    field :driver_id
    field :avatar, :active_storage
    field :pictures, :multiple_active_storage
field :pictures, :multiple_active_storage
field :pictures, :multiple_active_storage


  end
```

I still got only 2 fields one for the avatar the other for only one picture. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

first, to delete works you need to declare it this way.

```
  belongs_to :driver
  has_one_attached :avatar
  has_many_attached :pictures


  attr_accessor :remove_avatar

  attr_accessor :remove_pictures

  after_save do
    avatar.purge if remove_avatar == '1'
    Array(remove_pictures).each { |id| pictures.find_by_id(id).try(:purge) }
  end


  rails_admin do
    field :driver_id
    field :avatar, :active_storage do 
      delete_method :delete_avatar
    end

    field :pictures, :multiple_active_storage do 
      delete_method :delete_pictures
    end

  end
```

second, it will show only one field to pictures but is a multi-upload file so you can send as many files as you want